# Ordering Items by List Item in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a product that have list of price, Can i order by price?

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductPrice> ProductPrices{ get; set; }
}
public class ProductPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Degree{ get; set; }
    public int Price{ get; set; }
}
```

I use this code.but don't ordered

```
_db.Products.Select(m=>m.ProductPrices.OrderBy(o=>o.Price))
```

Comment: So on which price do you want to sort, when a product has multiple?

Comment: What do you want ordered? The products ordered by the min price of each, or the products in any order with each products prices in ascending order? ( If you have `{title: apple, prices: [0.12,0.09]},{title:banana, prices:[0.08,0.09]}` do you want `{title: apple, prices: [0.09,0.12]},{title:banana, prices:[0.08,0.09]}` or do you want `{title: banana, prices: [0.08,0.09]},{title:apple, prices:[0.12,0.09]}` (or even do you want both the prices sorting and then the products sorting by first price? `{title: banana, prices: [0.08,0.09]},{title:apple, prices:[0.09,0.12]}`

Comment: I want to sort products that have max price. for example `{title: apple, prices: [0.09,0.12]},{title:banana, prices:[0.08,0.09]}` and min price `{title: banana, prices: [0.08,0.09]},{title:apple, prices:[0.12,0.09]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Select`, juste call `OrderBy` and `Max` directly

```
var listSorted = _db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductPrices.Max(pp => pp.Price))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want sort product items with max price.

Comment: @andyb952 yes, I think so, but have you another solution?

Comment: this order productprice, but i want order products

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order products by the maximum product price then do this:

```
_db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductPrices.Max(pp => pp.Price))
```